# What is the data type in ASP.NET Core for decimal(18,2) in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have a Amount column in database which is in Varchar datatype, I am retrieving the data from table and I am casting for the amount  should be returned as (12345.0,111.00) like this, so here I am casting with decimal, but in my ASP.NET Core the output data type is mismatching. How can I get the output like this (12345.0,111.00) from both API and database.

```
 select max(cast(Amount as DECIMAL(18,2))) as HighestBid from Bids where PostId = @ip_Postid
     and Amount != ''
 select min(cast(Amount as DECIMAL(18,2))) as HighestBid from Bids where PostId = @ip_Postid
     and Amount != ''
```

API Output :

```
public class GetUserBidOutPut
{
    [Key]
    public decimal? HighestBid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing a numeric value as varchar?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) may help. Consider changing the Amount column data type to an appropriate one.

Comment: I must admit, `varchar`, `float` and `money` are all poor candidates for what appears to be a monetary value.

Comment: just to be clear, as written, your selects will return 2 datasets.  Also you seem to have a copy/paste error in the second select, based on `min()` I think you meant to write `as LowestBid`

Comment: @squillman even if i change the Amount column varchar to money still getting API error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Decimal'.

Comment: You want `decimal`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-6.0) in .NET for exact numeric types with fixed decimal places, not `int`.

Comment: Browne  even if i change the int to decimal  still getting API error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Decimal

Comment: So why is your query returning an Int32?

Comment: Are you missing the code which loads the data? Because if you cast to money/decimal in the database it won't be returning an INT, and if your proposal is DECIMAL, then there is no INT in the picture, what do you use to retrieve the data and load it into your object?

Comment: @DaleK updated nmy question, but still getting the error :Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Decimal'.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using int and float in your Model and SQL? use **DECIMAL** instead.

```
select max(cast(Amount as DECIMAL(18,2))) as HighestBid from Bids where PostId = @ip_Postid
     and Amount != ''
 select min(cast(Amount as DECIMAL(18,2))) as HighestBid from Bids where PostId = @ip_Postid
     and Amount != ''
```

And,

```
public class GetUserBidOutPut
{
    [Key]
    public Decimal? HighestBid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @heyharshill getting  Error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Decimal'.

Comment: @TentuBharthi Could you please share the piece of code at which point you are getting errors?